# XCode, SpriteKit: How do I trigger two actions with just touch?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

My simple game idea insists of a node that grows in size, reaches a certain size, then goes back to its original size and this loops. I have it so once I touch the screen, this triggers. I want it so after I've touched it for the first time and touch it for a second, even if it is in the middle of increasing in size or decreasing, I would like it switch to the opposite action it is doing. e.g if it is increasing in size and I tap before it deceases, it decreases anyway... Here's my code. What do I need to do? Cheers!

```
import SpriteKit
```

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(color: .blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    addChild(self.player)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    //SCALE//

    let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(6.0, duration: 1)
    let scaleDown = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 1)

    let scaleUpGroup = SKAction.group([scaleUp])
    let scaleDownGroup = SKAction.group([scaleDown])

    let scaleUpAndDownSequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleUpGroup, scaleDownGroup])

    let loop = SKAction.repeatActionForever(scaleUpAndDownSequence)

    self.player.runAction(loop, withKey: "scalingUpAndDown")

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this is to use a Boolean value as a kind of toggle switch. Make a var named "isReversed" or something and create a sequence with the order switched.

```
let scaleDownAndUp = SKAction.sequence([scaleDownGroup, scaleUpGroup])
let reverseLoop = SKAction.repeatActionForever(scaleDownAndUp)

var isReversed = false

 if !isReversed {
    self.player.removeActionForKey("scalingDownAndUp")
    self.player.runAction(loop, withKey: "scalingUpAndDown")
    isReversed = true
} else {
    self.player.removeActionForKey("scalingUpAndDown")
    self.player.runAction(reverseLoop, withKey: "scalingDownAndUp")
    isReversed = false
}
```

This will check isReversed when you tap the screen, perform the correct action and then toggle isReversed to its alternate state.

I didnt test this, but if something is slightly off, the general idea is sound and should be easily implemented.

Comment: Cheers. Top man. I'll check this later on and let you know if it works!